# Is my script vulnerable to sql injections?

Tags: php, sql-injection, sql-insert

First thank you for reading my question.

During this days, i saw that there are a lot of "malicious" url query running at my website,so i was afraid if my php script is vulnerable to sql injections.

My url structure is: http://mywebsite.com/post.php?id=7573
To get all info i need from a post i use the post id from URL.

To "clear" this ID i use this method:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string ($id);
$safeID = intval(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $id));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM web_content WHERE state = '1' AND ID = '$safeID'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
.........
```

Please i need to know if the safeID, that is sent to database, is really "SAFE".

Thank you

Comment: Switch to using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli). `mysql_` functions are deprecated!

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is. But it's also the wrong order. First filtering, then context escaping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to prevent SQL injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: @mario, its not a dublicate dude, this is a heavy problem for me, instead of checking dublicated or not , give an answer if you can.

Comment: Sirko's advice is good. look into it. +1

Comment: @Avin: We're not here to explain the same stuff over and over again, just because someone demands personal tutoring.

Comment: mario please just ignore my post, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be just as easy as using `intval($id)`

Comment: what intval do ? can you explain please ?

Comment: Checks that the variable is an integer and if it isn't returns zero

Answer (score 1):

It is, but doing the `preg_replace` is not needed since `mysql_real_escape_string` already escapes all 'bad' characters.

Comment: i see some comands like :
' union all select null,(select concat(0x7e,0x27,0x7233646D3076335F68766A5F696E6A656374696F6E,0x27,0x7e) limit 0,1),null,null where

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string will take care of this value so that it can do no harm to you. But, of course, in this particular case, you can do the extra step to just keep the sql query shorter.

Answer (score 0):

it's safe. mysql_real_escape_string and preg_replace are not even needed since intval only returns an integer.

be aware though that intval returns 0 on failure. so receiving 'bla' for $id is just the same as receiving '0'. if that's no problem to your logic, don't worry about it.